# C++ generic multi-platform solution to get mac address

Tags: android, c++, ios, mac-address

Helo,

I want to build up a library using C++ which will have a function that retrieves a device's MAC address.
The trick is to make it work at least on iOS/Android, possibly Windows.

Not sure since solutions I found are basically system specific.

Answer (score 1):

You will need platform specific solutions which query the operating system or hardware directly. Please note that there are likely to be multiple MAC addresses for various devices.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any cross-platform way to get any information about a network interface, MAC address including. Even if you restrict yourself to Ethernet MAC addresses, and to interfaces conforming to (R)MII specification, you can't access the MII registers from user (thus portable) code.

The only way you could do something like that is to provide an abstraction layer, which will use platform specific code "under" the cross-platform API. There are probably some libraries/frameworks that can do that (I'd check Qt, for example), though using the whole framework for this single purpose will probably be overkill.